# ReactJS - How to setSate in a map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got an object with another object inside and I need to render the DOM like this:

- Event

  - Tickets 1

    - Lot 1

      - Name
    - Lot 2

      - Name
    - Lot 3

      - Name
  - Ticket 2

    - Lot 1

      - Name
    - Lot 2

      - Name

```
{ this.state.dates.map((date, i) =>
    <span className="event-date" key={i}>
     { date.date }
    </span>
    this.setState({tickets: date.tickets}) //Here, I need to update an object to map in another place
)}
```

> ./src/pages/Event/Event.js
>   Syntax error: D:/YEAPPS/marketplace/pwa/src/pages/Event/Event.js: Unexpected token, expected , (54:32)

[Click to see the object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5KiR.png)

Comment: what is the purpose of the setState? you are overriding "tickets" on every iteration, please provide more context to get the best answer

Comment: I am not sure about this but won't it be easier to calculate new state once and then use setState to pass new object in, rather then recalculate it per item.

Answer (score 3):

Do not call setState from within a render function, it will cause unnecessary rerenders, i.e. do not update the state with your tickets here

Set up your state within the component using other lifecycle hooks, e.g. `componentDidMount`, then simply map over your `this.state.tickets.map()`, or as you are already doing, `this.state.dates.map()`

Comment: He told you what to do, you should definitely not be setting state in a loop or setting it in render. If you need data from this array you should be doing it when you receive it from the server, which might not be in a react view at all

Comment: can you provide a sample object of how dates and tickets relate? I can't see how dates are relevant in your recent edit

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve like this:

```js
                        {
                            this.state.tickets.map((ticket, i) => (
                                <div key={i}>
                                    <div className="row">
                                        <div className="col">
                                            <h3 className="ticket-name">{ ticket.name }</h3>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    {ticket.lot.map((lot, j) => 
                                        <div className="row" key={i}>
                                            <div className="col-8">
                                                <h5 className="lot-name">{ lot.name }</h5>
                                                <h6 className="lot-price">
                                                    R$ { lot.price.replace('.', ',') } <br />
                                                    <small>(R$ { lot.price.replace('.', ',') } + R$ { lot.price_tax.replace('.', ',') })</small>
                                                </h6>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="col-4">
                                                <ChooseQuantity />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    )}
                                    <hr />
                                </div>
                                )
                            )
                        }
```